# turn displays on with python under Windows 7 64bit

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to turn displays on using python. Found [this](https://github.com/arjun024/turn-off-screen/blob/master/platform-specific/turnoff_win8.1.py) code very useful but the problem is that it is turning display on for a brief moment and after like 1 second all displays are still 'entering power-save mode'. How can I make this 'power on' feature permanently?

Comment: The linked code appears to be turning the displays _off_, so what do you expect?

Comment: I would expect that changing last parameter in win32gui.SendMessage() from '2' to '-1' (as documentation says) will do the trick. But it doesn't and behaviour is like I described in the question above.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011141/turn-off-on-monitor-cant-turn-on

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint, **martineau**! Simple sending message like that will not work:

```
win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST, win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)
```

I also tried:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(100, 20)
```

and

```
pygame.mouse.set_pos((random.choice(range(600)), random.choice(range(600))))
```

to utilise mouse, but this is nothing when compare to:

```
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,100,20)
```

**mouse_event did the trick** as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3721094/6312207)